# Webpack sourcemaps: how to change the sourcemap path in output

Tags: webpack, source-maps

Currently the sourcemaps I generate are using an appending of the entry path and the relative paths in each file. Is there a way to flatten that so I don't end up with "foo/.././bar.js" as the sourcemap path? Chrome will present these in a collapsed manner in the dev tools and I'd like to flatten them out.